# how to delimit integers in java?

Tags: java, integer, delimiter

I have a integer value coming from command line. Its like 12345 or 2343455435 without any delimit characters. How can I get individual pieces of that integer, say like for 12345 I want something like 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Just iterate over all signs and add a comma after each?

Comment: Is the integer value a String or an int?

Comment: Well, it is an int value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over all chiffres of the Integer and add a comma if necessary. Something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 123456;

        String s = Integer.toString(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i) + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this :

```
String numberString = "123456789";
for(byte numberByte:numberString.getBytes()){
    int number = numberByte - '0';
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] pieces = Integer.toString(myInt).split("[\\d]");
Integer [] numbers = new Integer[pieces.length];
Integer counter = 0;
for (String n : pieces)
    numbers[counter++] = Integer.parseInt(n);
```

That's assuming it's an integer. Otherwise:

```
String[] pieces = myNumString.split("[\\d]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizers to get string based on specific tokens or you can just substring the String (use Integer.toString(yourInteger))

```
int start = 1;
int end = 4;
String substr = "aString".substring(start, end);
```